Search and Edit/Update Data Script for Google Sheets
NOTE: I have abandoned this approach for a different approach that is successful. Thank you though.
I am new to script writing. I am very familiar with regular old functions but not very familiar with script.
This is what I am trying to do.



On the "Enter" tab, as shown above, people will input the ID number assigned. As soon as the id number is assigned, my script should search the data sheet to recall any information provided for that ID. If there is no information with the ID number or information needs to be updated/edited with the ID number, then the tester would input or change the data. They would use the "Submit" checkbox to save/update the data. I want to use a checkbox (i.e. to use onEdit) as buttons don't work on cells or tablets.
The ID numbers will be pre-set as there are limited number of ID's.
Link for my Google Sheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rkU64kHZ9UmlZH36Y3aXmTliyCX5-XlTKc3SzndmUoI/edit?gid=385481476#gid=385481476
I have been trying to following Youtube videos on Google Sheets scripts for beginners. Then I would search specifically for my issue.
I am hoping that someone would be able to help me as I know absolutely no one with more computer knowledge than I do, and I am average skilled.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images might be helpful, but code and sample data should be added as text.

Also, the question looks to be too for this site. Please remember that questions on this site should be about a specific problem unique to programming. It's mentioned that the script should be triggered by checking the checkbox, but the code doesn't include a function named onEdit, and there is no mention of the use of an installable on-edit trigger.

The scenario is easy to describe but the coding is more involved and layered than it first seems. There are two discrete processes, both initiated by an onEdit trigger and making use of Event Objects, and you may benefit by focusing on one, then the other, and then combining the two. My reading of the processes: 1) enter an ID, search for a match on another sheet, display something on screen (Match/No match). 2) check a "Submit" box, check if a match on another sheet; if no match, add data to the sheet; if a match, amend existing data, display something on screen to show process is complete.

If you wish, you might care to limit this question to to dealing with finding a match for an ID. If so, then I can offer an answer tailored to your scenario, and you can research how to handle the "Submit" button, etc.

I am new to script writing. Not to worry, we've all been there. Having said that, the fieldRange and fieldValues variables are not newbie code. May I ask where/how you developed this code,  does the code work when you trigger it, and what (exactly) is wrong with the code?

Submitting data using button
inline with Tedinoz's comment about the Submit button.
I've added a few codes on the script that you've provided.
Previous code:
If (!cellFound) return
const row = cellFound.getRow()

Updated code:
if (!cellFound) {
    Logger.log("ID not found");
    EnterWS.getRange("E5").setValue(false);
    return;
  }

Also i added some feature once the data is submitted alert will come up
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Data has been successfully updated.');

Here's the complete code that I used.
function myFunction() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const EnterWS = ss.getSheetByName("Enter");
  const dWS = ss.getSheetByName("D");

  const idCell = EnterWS.getRange("D5").getValue();

 
  const cellFound = dWS.getRange("A:A")
                      .createTextFinder(idCell)
                      .matchCase(true)
                      .matchEntireCell(true)
                      .findNext();

 
  if (!cellFound) {
    Logger.log("ID not found");
    EnterWS.getRange("E5").setValue(false);
    return;
  }

  const row = cellFound.getRow();
  
  const fieldRange = ["D5", "H9", "I9", "J9", "H11", "I11", "J11", "D13", "D15"];

  const fieldValues = fieldRange.map(f => EnterWS.getRange(f).getValue());

  dWS.getRange(row, 1, 1, fieldValues.length).setValues([fieldValues]);

  fieldRange.forEach(f => EnterWS.getRange(f).clearContent());

  EnterWS.getRange("E5").setValue(false);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Data has been successfully updated.');
}

Sample Output:

Reference
How to create a button in Google Sheets
Pop up alert messages in Google Sheets
